# Project runs in older version of IDEA, but not newer

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I have a spring boot application that runs and functions just fine in IDEA 15.0.4.

Today I tried running it in the latest release of IDEA 2016.1
and I get the following error

2016-03-17 10:06:17.888  WARN 84730 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configClientBootstrapConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

and then execution stops.

Is there an additional step I have to do to get this to work in the newer version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by simply re-cloning the repository and setting up a new project.